# AngularJS with JQuery validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, jquery-validate

I'm using angularjs to bring some data from server,
it's works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
myAppcontroller("AgentCtrl", function ($scope, leadsService) {
    $scope.showUsers = false;
    $scope.cityName = { 'query': ''};

    $scope.findAgent = function() {
        leadsService.get("/api/usersapi/agents/" + $scope.cityName.query).then(function(out) {
            $scope.agents = out;
            $scope.showUsers = true;
            $scope.selectedOption = $scope.agents[0];
        });
    };

    $scope.init = function (cityName) {
        $scope.cityName.query = cityName;
        if ((typeof cityName !== "undefined")) {
            $scope.findAgent();
        } 
    };

    $scope.$watch('cityName.query', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.cityName.query.watch = newValue;
    });
});
```

Now I have a validation error in *`Chrome`*... (I'm using **`jQuery validation`**).

Here is the code I'm using to disable this error:

```
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var isValid = /^\d{4}[\/\-]\d{1,2}[\/\-]\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$/.test(value);
    alert(isValid);

    return isValid;
}, '');
```

But when I use the jquery code angularjs stops working...
Some one have met this issue??? If so how to solve it?

Comment: any specific reason for using jquery validation

Comment: Yes I'm using mvc web project

Comment: What error?  Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Make sure your jQuery loaded before your Angluarjs?